# Error when adding reference to class library in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, class-library

I have created a class library to a current solution in visual studio 2017 and I have added a reference to it in my main application.

But when I build I get this error

`Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error Project 'C:\Users\declanmarks\Documents\oversurgeryassignment\OverSurgeryAssignment\Utility\Utility.csproj' targets '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'. OverSurgeryAssignment`

I cannot figure out how to fix this.

Comment: You need to change your target frameworks to be compatible.

Comment: What target frameworks are compatible.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md. For .NET Standard 2.0 you need .NET Framework 4.6.1 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `Target framework` version of the project that is referencing the class library matches the version in the class library.

You can get to the `Target framework` option by right-clicking the project in the solution explorer and clicking on `Properties`. The `Target framework` option is on the `Application` tab of the project properties window.